# Posting page with dynamic image on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a site in which the user creates a dynamic image, and would like the user to be able to post her creation on Facebook. The way I wanted to achieve this is via the standard "like" and "share" buttons ( using XFBML) - I dynamically change their URL to a **page** containing the user image.

The problem is that Facebook posts the **correct** URL but with a generic picture, and not the user generated picture.

In the past I used to give the **image** url - and then I would get the right picture. But this is not what I wan't now - I wan't the link to be to a full feature page.

The target page does specify og:img to the dynamic image - but it seems FB does not use it...

Any ideas how I can control the image FB shows on the post?

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions on the image

> the thumbnail's width AND height must be at least 50 pixels, and cannot exceed 130x110 pixels. The ratio of both height divided by width and width divided by height (w/h, h/w) cannot exceed 3.0

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/